# What is Parser Inserted Script in HTML5 specs

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, dom

HTML5 specs mentions parser inserted script and give it's definition as "*The second is a flag indicating whether the element was "parser-inserted". Initially, script elements must have this flag unset. It is set by the HTML parser and the XML parser on script elements they insert and affects the processing of those elements*" in http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-LC/scripting-1.html
Can some one explain it with an example which one is a parser inserted script and which one is not?

Comment: Further below is an example: *"When an XSLT transformation program is triggered by an <?xml-stylesheet?> processing instruction and the browser implements a direct-to-DOM transformation, script elements created by the XSLT processor need to be marked "parser-inserted" and run in document order (modulo scripts marked defer or async), asynchronously while the transformation is occurring."*

Answer (score 0):

From React-DOM:
Create the script via .innerHTML so its "parser-inserted" flag is set to true and it does not execute.
Example:

```
<script>
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.innerHTML = 'alert("hi")';
document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

Script will not execute.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware scripts that are either written in the source HTML or injected to the document via `document.write()` are considered as "parser-inserted."